# Big datasets panel fixed effects

Tags: bigdata

I'm working with big datasets, namely, a panel with more than 20 million observations and more than 5 thousand municipalities. Does anybody knows a feasible way of including fixed effects by municipality in this context? My R stops and do not run. Thanks!

so far I just couldn't succeed using package of FE, and including more than 5K dummies is a bit too much as well